# Иконка в лаунчере не четкая

Tags: android, иконки

Уже надоело, какие бы иконки я не создавал, все они выглядят нечетко, вот скриншот (приложение ANT)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама иконка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весит 60кб, разрешение 3000*3000. Даже с таким разрешением выглядит нечетко. На устройстве Android 7.1 выставлен кастомный DPI, но иконки других приложений выглядят нормально. Что не так?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить иконку через `File` - `New` - `Image Asset` - `Launcher icons`. PS. У картинки -- *разрешение*.

Comment: Ну края у картинки весьма размытые, и если эту картинку уменьшить в n-ое количество раз, то размытие соответственно будет ещё больше. Нарисуйте картинку с четкими не размытыми краями и при масштабировании размытие не будет появляться

Comment: Плюс лаунч иконки нужно класть в директории `mipmap-...` а не `drawable-...`, как для остальных иконок.

Comment: @eugeneek, почему?

Comment: Потому что гугл так советует. Ненужные разрешения ресурсов дропаются при установке приложения, но для иконки лаунчера может понадобиться её увеличенная версия. Ресурсы в папках `mipmap` не дропаются. Подробнее [тут](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/goodbye-launcher-drawables-hello-mipmaps/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причем тут разрешение картинки вес и проч. - если у вас оригинал картинки с явными следами апскейлинга? То бишь вы взяли иконочку типа 32*32 и растянули ее до 3000*3000, но исходное качество при этом ведь не изменилось...

Стандартный подход здесь обычно такой:

1. Берется Coreldraw/Corel PhotoPaint/Photoshop
2. Рисуется векторная или растрово-векторная картинка, то есть картинка не пиксельная, а нарисованная с применением графических примитивов типа: круг, линия, прямоугольник, многоугольник, true-type шрифт, заливка и проч.
3. Сохраняется в формате PNG с разрешением не хуже 512*512 (то есть вектор "выгоняется" в растр)
4. Из полученного растра "выгоняем" нужного размера иконочку.

Comment: Мне показалось странным, почему для векторной графики вы упомянули фотошоп, но про скетч/иллюстратор ничего не сказали :)

Comment: Потому что дизайнеры не любят скетч/иллюстратор, а предпочитают работать в кореле или фотошопе, впрочем, это не принципиально. На вкус и цвет, как говорится

Comment: И да, кстати, Google сам [рекомендует/предполагает Photoshop](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

Comment: Не знаю, что за дизайнер будет предпочитать фотошоп для векторной графики, вместо скетча :)

Comment: Я ничего не увеличивал, ее рисовал я в фотошопе